# How to remove space above the <div> tag?

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS, and I want to create a fixed-width page which has a silver background color. I also want the background color outside of the fixed-width area to be black.

The problem is that there is a small black gap above the fixed-width area (above the heading), and I would like to remove this black gap, so that it's replaced with silver color.

How do I solve this?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to my Homepage</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <h1>Welcome to my homepage.</h1>
            <p>This is just a test.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {background-color: #000000;}
.main {
    width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
body {padding:0; margin:0; background-color:#000; }
```

Comment: Typically, setting the margin is all that is necessary.  However, up until a few versions ago, Opera set the padding and not the margin (if you ask me, I believe their original implementation was more correct...)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
border-width:0px;
```

border and margin are two different things... here's a nice picture for you:

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/30-the-css-layout-model-boxes-border/

Answer (score 0):

You can do below:

```
body {margin:0; padding: 0; background-color:#000; } 

.main {   
position: absolute;
width: 640px;    
left: 50%;
margin-left: -320px;
background-color: silver; 
}
```

Comment: What's with the random absolute positioning added for no reason?

Answer (score 0):

problems like this one will be quite common when writing HTML & CSS, it is a hotly debated subject but I would strongly recommend you use a reset style sheet.

All browsers have their own set of rules as to how elements are displayed on a webpage, a reset style sheet goes a very long way to minimise the effect of browser specific style meaning your code reads much more logically and it easier to spot what is going on especially when you have a problem. That said, even with a reset style sheet you should always cross browser check a project as there are always quirks.

Here is one of the most widely used reset style sheets.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Just paste this above your website CSS on your style.css sheet or create a new stylesheet called reset.css and reference it BEFORE your site.css.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having a margin/padding on the body element:  it makes the document readable when there's no styling.  Reset stylesheets should never be suggested to anyone who is just learning, they're meant for people who understand the implications of using one.

Comment: i couldnt disagree with you more. What is point in learning how to develop for web (commercially or not) without udnerstanding the basics? one of these being the use of reset stylesheets!

Resetting browser behaviour like this will help anybody who is learning understanding exactly how what they write affects their element without individual browsers affecting the outcome.